# Preventing onbeforeunload() being called when refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom-events

I have a web page where I am destroying the session when the user closes the tab or browser. This is my script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
document.write("<?php session_destroy();
?>");
 }
```

My problem is I want to destroy the session only when the browser is closed. which event should i use? Is this possible in all browsers? Please help.

Comment: This doesnt work fine, your session will be destroyed on page load. You cant just mix javascript and PHP, it wont work since Javascript is client-side and PHP is server side.

Comment: How can we destroy a session on closing the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are destroyed when the browser closes by default. This is actually controlled by the PHP configuration option `session.cookie_lifetime`. [From the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime):

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0.

What you are trying to do, explicitly destroy the session data at the server side when the browser is closed, cannot be done. There is no way to tell (from Javascript at least) whether the page is being reloaded or the browser is being closed - both events fire `onunload()` and `onbeforeunload()` in the same manner.

The other point about this is that it would involve sending a request to the server as the browser closes, which is highly unlikely to be allowed and could not be relied upon - after all, what if the server failed to respond? It could result in the browser hanging on close waiting for a response, which would ruin the user experience and the browser developers would never allow it.